# Clickhouse bloom filter index seems too slow

Tags: clickhouse

I had executed the following query  but it has processed ~1B rows and took total time of 75 seconds for a simple count.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM events_distributed
WHERE (orgId = '174a4727-1116-4c5c-8234-ab76f2406c4a') AND (timestamp >= '2022-12-05 00:00:00.000000000')

Query id: e4312ff5-6add-4757-8deb-d68e0f3e29d9

┌──count()─┐
│ 13071204 │
└──────────┘

1 row in set. Elapsed: 74.951 sec. Processed 979.00 million rows, 8.26 GB (13.06 million rows/s., 110.16 MB/s.)
```

I am wondering how I can speed this up? My events table has the following `partition by` and `order by columns` and a bloom filter index on orgid

```
PARTITION BY toDate(timestamp)
ORDER BY (timestamp);
```

```
INDEX idx_orgid orgid TYPE bloom_filter(0.01) GRANULARITY 1,
```

Below is the execution plan

```
EXPLAIN indexes = 1
SELECT count(*)
FROM events_distributed
WHERE (orgid = '174a4727-1116-4c5c-8234-ab76f240fc4a') AND (timestamp >= '2022-12-05 00:00:00.000000000') AND (timestamp <= '2022-12-06 00:00:00.000000000')

Query id: 879c2ce5-c4c7-4efc-b0e2-25613848afad

┌─explain────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Expression ((Projection + Before ORDER BY))                                                                │
│   MergingAggregated                                                                                        │
│     Union                                                                                                  │
│       Aggregating                                                                                          │
│         Expression (Before GROUP BY)                                                                       │
│           Filter (WHERE)                                                                                   │
│             ReadFromMergeTree (users.events)                                                               │
│             Indexes:                                                                                       │
│               MinMax                                                                                       │
│                 Keys:                                                                                      │
│                   timestamp                                                                                │
│                 Condition: and((timestamp in (-Inf, '1670284800']), (timestamp in ['1670198400', +Inf)))   │
│                 Parts: 12/342                                                                              │
│                 Granules: 42122/407615                                                                     │
│               Partition                                                                                    │
│                 Keys:                                                                                      │
│                   toDate(timestamp)                                                                        │
│                 Condition: and((toDate(timestamp) in (-Inf, 19332]), (toDate(timestamp) in [19331, +Inf))) │
│                 Parts: 12/12                                                                               │
│                 Granules: 42122/42122                                                                      │
│               PrimaryKey                                                                                   │
│                 Keys:                                                                                      │
│                   timestamp                                                                                │
│                 Condition: and((timestamp in (-Inf, '1670284800']), (timestamp in ['1670198400', +Inf)))   │
│                 Parts: 12/12                                                                               │
│                 Granules: 30696/42122                                                                      │
│               Skip                                                                                         │
│                 Name: idx_orgid                                                                        │
│                 Description: bloom_filter GRANULARITY 1                                                    │
│                 Parts: 8/12                                                                                │
│                 Granules: 20556/30696                                                                      │
│       ReadFromRemote (Read from remote replica)                                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

32 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.129 sec.
```

How can I speed up this query? because processing 1B rows to give a count of 13M sounds like something is total off. Does creating a `SET` index on `orgid` any better? because I will have a max of 10K orgs

The queries I typicall run are

```
SELECT org_level, min(timestamp) as minTimeStamp,max(timestamp) as maxTimeStamp, toStartOfInterval(toDateTime(timestamp), INTERVAL <step> second) as roundedDownTs, count(*) as cnt, orgid 
        FROM events_distributed
        WHERE orgid = 'foo' and timestamp BETWEEN <one week>
        GROUP BY roundedDownTs, orgid, org_level
        ORDER BY roundedDownTs DESC;
```

please note `<step>` here would be  any of the following values `0, 60, 240, 1440, 10080`

and another query for a one week time slice but it can be any time slice and always want the results in descending order because of timeseries

```
SELECT org_text
FROM events_distributed
WHERE (orgid = '174a4727-1116-4c5c-8234-ab76f2406c4a') AND (timestamp >= '2022-12-01 00:00:00.000000000' and timestamp <= '2022-12-07 00:00:00.000000000') order by timestamp DESC LIMIT 51;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use primary index

I suggest is to use

```
PARTITION BY toDate(timestamp)
ORDER BY (orgId, timestamp)
```

https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/

And remove bloom_filter index.

Comment: should I do `ORDER BY (orgId, timestamp)` or 
`ORDER BY (orgId, toStartOfHour(timestamp), timestamp)` ?

Comment: What is the type of `timestamp` ?

Comment: `Datetime64(9)` nanosecond timestamp. Also I dont need data beyond a month. 99.9999% of the queries are all about most recent week! so the recent 7 days worth of data is very important.

Comment: i would use `primary key (orgId, toStartOfHour(timestamp)) ORDER BY (orgId, toStartOfHour(timestamp), timestamp)`

Comment: can you please give me a one liner on how that would help to get to the rows qucker?

Comment: hahaha. You need `magic=on`.

Comment: What query is the most typical for your system?

Comment: Just edited the question with the two examples of my queries that I run all the time. please take a look at the `<step>` parameter of my aggregate query. The ORDER BY columns is tricky because from the past experince with user id it seems to work well for non aggregated query but not the aggregated query so trying to find ORDER BY that works well for both of those two query case. Also paritioning should I do `toYYYYMM` instead of `toDate`? that way all my data will be in single parition. not sure the downsides

Comment: Originally you asked about `orgId`, now you show `userid` ? How many columns with UUID do you have? Which query do you need run ? `userid =...` or `orgId = ...`

Comment: sorry, edited! user = org in my case and I will have max of 10K orgs. we use it interchangebly because of legacy code. sorry about that

Comment: There is no other id other than orgId at this point!